# Need to display two items at a time within a horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to display two views within a horizontal scroll as shown in the picture below. I am wondering the possible ways to achieve this because the output that I have achieved is far from the requirement as we can see in the screen grabs below:-

[image: Required Output]

Here is a part of my layout which describes the view that i have implemented:-

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageGallery"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

To the above view i then created a linear layout with vertical orientation and added to it an imageview, and 3 text view as shown in the below code snippet:-

```
     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private View getVerticalLinearLayout(Integer image){
        LinearLayout verticalLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        verticalLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,2.0f));
        verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        verticalLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layout_border));
        verticalLayout.addView(scaleImage((ImageView) getImageView(image)));
        verticalLayout.addView(getTextView("Book Name",14,"#444444"));
        verticalLayout.addView(getTextView("Author Name",12,"#444444"));
        verticalLayout.addView(getTextView("Lender Name",12,"444444"));
        return verticalLayout;

    }
```

However what I have managed to achieve can be seen in the image below [image]

Comment: Please state your issue and reformat your question.

Comment: Do you want the width of each item to be half the parent's width, and scroll freely? Or do you want the scrolling to be like swapping pages, where each page is 2 items on each page?

Comment: The item should be divided into half the parent's width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design your book views as individual layout file. You can then instantiate it using the LayoutInflater and populate it with your data and then finally add them individually to your `imageGallery` layout.

To make exactly two views appear at a time on the screen you have to know the screen width. This is possible via `DisplayMetrics` or you can call `getWidth()` on a view that covers the screen fully horizontally. Once you get that width the `bookView` layouts that you will be adding to your horizontal scroll view need to have their width set to `screenWidth/2`.

Comment: I have already been able to populate the gallery view, its just that I want to display only two items as in the first screen grab, i.e display two books equally in the screen

Comment: And it needs to be horizontally scrollable too?

Comment: Yup .. horizontally scrollable too !!

Comment: Cool ..  I tried by passing static width value and it did work .. So it seems i just need to add a function to get the exact value as you described and it should work ...

Comment: Yeah, in fact if you give some id so your HorzontalScrollView you can call `getWidth()` on it too to get screen width.